# Matrix Derivative Problem

Tags: matrix-calculus

Sorry for boring you my friends. I am haunted by a question of matrix derivative.

$q$ is a vector of dimension $n\times1$;

$A_1$, $A_2$, $...$  $A_n$ and $B$ are matrix with constant coefficients of dimension $n\times n$;

$A_1q$ , $A_2q$ $...$ and $A_nq$ become $n$ columns of matrix  $\left[ A_1q \space A_2q ... \space A_nq \right]$ whose dimension is $n \times n$.

I would like to perform the following matrix derivative:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\left( \left[ A_1q \space A_2q ... \space A_nq \right]Bq\right)^\text{T}$$

The first part of derivative is done, but I don't know how to perform derivative on the second part.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\left( \left[ A_1q \space A_2q ... \space A_nq \right]Bq\right)^\text{T} = B^\text{T}\left[ A_1q \space A_2q ... \space A_nq \right]^\text{T}+ q^\text{T}B^\text{T}\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\left(\left[ A_1q \space A_2q ... \space A_nq \right]^\text{T} \right)$$

Thanks in advance for taking a look!

P.S.
Thanks for your response.Let $p$ and $q$ are all n-element vector.

$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial q} = \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \frac{\partial p_1}{\partial q_1}&...&\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial q_n}
\\ ...&...&...\\ 
\frac{\partial p_n}{\partial q_1}&...&\frac{\partial p_n}{\partial q_n}\end {array} \right]$$

Comment: How is $\frac{\partial}{\partial q}$ defined?  If $q=[q_1\cdots q_n]'$, then is $\frac{\partial}{\partial q}=\frac{\partial}{\partial q_1}+\frac{\partial}{\partial q_2}+\cdots+\frac{\partial}{\partial q_n}$?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The matrix differentiation is defined as the Jacobian matrix transformation.

Comment: I suggest writing $\begin{bmatrix}A_1q&A_2q&\cdots&A_nq\end{bmatrix}$ as a sum of matrices.  I.e., rewrite $A_1q$ as $A_1qD_1$ where $D_1$ has a $1$ in the upper left corner and $0$'s elsewhere.  If you follow this pattern, your matrix becomes a sum of matrices which you should be able to differentiate.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it easiest to study this when the matrix and vector products are rewritten as sums over coordinates ([Einstein sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), if you allow).

The object you want to differentiate is the transpose of a vector $v$, where

$$v_i = (A_l)_{ik}q_k B_{lm}q_m,$$

and differentiation is defined by

$$\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial q}\right)_{ij} = \frac{\partial p_i}{\partial q_j}$$

so let's just write (the transposition can be left for later)

$$\begin{aligned}
\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial q}\right)_{ij}
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial q_j} \left((A_l)_{ik}q_k B_{lm}q_m\right) \\
&= (A_l)_{ik}\delta_{jk} B_{lm}q_m + (A_l)_{ik}q_k B_{lm}\delta_{jm} \\
&= (A_l)_{ij} B_{lm}q_m + (A_l)_{ik}q_k B_{lj}.
\end{aligned}$$

The second term can be read as the $(i,j)$-th component of $[A_1q A_2q \ldots A_nq] B$, as you found. The first term will need to introduce a new notation because now each element of the $A_k$ must be accessed separately – that's what it says. It's a matrix whose $(i,j)$-th component is the scalar product of

$$a_{ij}^{\rm T} B q,$$

where $a_{ij}$ is a vector formed of $(i,j)$-th elements of the matrices $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$ in order.

**Written as a single multiplication, you'd need a rank-3 tensor here.** Composed of slices given by the $A$ matrices as $T_{ijk} = (A_k)_{ij}$, your problem has a natural formulation as

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial q_j} T_{lik}q_kB_{lm}q_m = T_{lij}B_{lm}q_m + T_{lik}q_kB_{lj},$$

it's the lack of the contraction $T_{li\circ} q_\circ$ that has no representation in your formalism except splitting into coordinate components and recombining.

Answer (score 3):

Your subscripted $A_k$ matrices are actually components of a third-order tensor, which I'll call ${\mathcal A}$.

It will be convenient to define the vector $b=Bq,\,\,$ whose differential is $$\eqalign{
db &= B\,dq \cr
}$$ Then in index notation, you're interested in the gradient of this vector 
$$\eqalign{
  y_{i} &= b_{j}\,{\mathcal A}_{jik}q_{k} \cr
}$$
Dropping the indices, you can write
$$\eqalign{
 y &= b^T{\mathcal A}q \cr\cr
dy  &= b^T{\mathcal A}\,dq + db^T{\mathcal A}q \cr
  &= b^T{\mathcal A}\,dq + dq^TB^T{\mathcal A}q \cr
  &= b^T{\mathcal A}\,dq + (B^T{\mathcal A}q)^T\,dq \cr\cr
\frac{\partial y}{\partial q}  &= b^T{\mathcal A} + (B^T{\mathcal A}q)^T \cr\cr
}$$
The first term can be written as a weighted sum of your $A_k$ matrices
$$\eqalign{
b^T{\mathcal A} &= \sum_{j=1}^n b_j\,A_j \cr
}$$
And you already know how to write the second term, since 
$$\eqalign{
 {\mathcal A}q &= [A_1q\,\,A_2q\,...A_nq\,] \cr
 (B^T{\mathcal A}q)^T &= ({\mathcal A}q)^TB \cr
  &= [A_1q\,\,A_2q\,...A_nq\,]^TB \cr
}$$

Answer (score 1):

Denote $C(q)=\left[ A_1q \space A_2q ... \space A_nq \right]$. If $B=(e_1, \dots, e_n)$ is the canonical basis of the space and $B^*=(e^1, \dots, e^n)$ the dual basis, the image of a vector $v$ under the map $C(q)$ is
$$D(q)=C(q)v=\sum_{i=1}^n [e^i(v)] A_i q $$ This is a sum of linear maps. Their derivatives are therefore themselves and 
$$D^\prime(q)h = \sum_{i=1}^n [e^i(v)] A_i h = [A_1 h \ A_2 h \ \dots \ A_n h ]v$$

Based on that you get
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\left(\left[ A_1q \space A_2q ... \space A_nq \right] \right)=\left[ A_1 e_i \space A_2 e_i ... \space A_n e_i \right]$$